# FTP Connect with Minio Server using Laravel

Tags: laravel, minio

I am trying to FTP connect with Minio server using Laravel.

In this file "**config/filesystems.php**" I add this code

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
        'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
        'root' => '/',
    ],
```

In this **.env** I add this code

```
FTP_HOST='127.0.0.1'
FTP_USERNAME='username'
FTP_PASSWORD='password'
```

But this shows me this error

**Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 at port 21.**

I also tried to give the proper host which is provided by when I start the MINIO server locally.

[image: Minio start]

Answer (score 0):

To use minio as an ftp server you need to specify the --ftp tag when you launch it : --ftp="address=:21"

source: [https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/file-transfer-protocol.html][1]